# Get folders from a class library

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have a Startup.cs file where I need to access resources files from "Resources" folder in a different class library.

I tried specifying path to dll and get all files from dll. I'm not sure how to get folder "Resources" from dll.

This is what I tried:

```
 string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $"Localization)}.dll", Path.GetFileName("Resoures"));               
 string[] files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path);
```

Expected:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path);
```

files should have the names of files from folder "Resources"

Actual:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
  'D:\home\site\wwwroot\DataAccess.Repositories.Localization.dll\Resoures'.
```

Comment: Those files are compiled in to the other assembly as resources, you won't be able to access them via the file system directly.  You will have to get them via `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`, passing in the assembly namespace, plus the relative path to the file from the `Resources` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the embedded resources using below code.

Please note that folders are not retained when you compile the project.

When you Mark a resource as embedded resource, that resource can be accessed

```
 string[] resourceNames = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
 foreach(string resourceName in resourceNames)
{
      Console.WriteLine(resourceName);
}
```